# Failed to resolve camel validator endpoint, caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null

Tags: java, apache-camel

forgive the title of this question, I wasn't even sure how to phrase it. My issue is that I'm working on a legacy camel project and want to move it forward from camel 2.9.2 to camel 2.13.2. The legacy project uses ant, not maven, and it has a bunch of camel (and other) jars in it (many of which it doesn't actually need, from what I can gather) but in any case it does work. I created a maven build file (pom.xml) and tried to recreate the necessary dependencies so that I could download the appropriate versions for camel-2.13.2. It builds fine. However, when I deploy it, when I start up I get an error on a xsd validator which was previously working fine in the old version. I do not see any other errors in my log.

Apologies, but it's a long stacktrace:

```
 09/10/2014 13:11 ERROR [main] (?:?) - &&& CamelManager exception 
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route EFileBatchRequestValidate at: >>> DoTry[[To[properties:{{validator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch}}], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.request.validatedtracsxsd}}], DoCatch[ null -> [To[exceptionResponseProcessor], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.request.rejected}}], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.response}}]]]]] <<< in route: Route(EFileBatchRequestValidate)[[From[properties:{{queue.ef... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: properties://%7B%7Bvalidator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch%7D%7D due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: validator://http://tomcat-test:8080/ecitationinternal/xsd/Odyssey/current/NM/NMEFileBatch.xsd due to: protocol = http host = null
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1363)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:122)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:157)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:147)
    at gov.nmcourts.camelvm.CamelManager.start(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nmcourts.camelvm.CamelManager.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route EFileBatchRequestValidate at: >>> DoTry[[To[properties:{{validator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch}}], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.request.validatedtracsxsd}}], DoCatch[ null -> [To[exceptionResponseProcessor], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.request.rejected}}], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.response}}]]]]] <<< in route: Route(EFileBatchRequestValidate)[[From[properties:{{queue.ef... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: properties://%7B%7Bvalidator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch%7D%7D due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: validator://http://tomcat-test:8080/ecitationinternal/xsd/Odyssey/current/NM/NMEFileBatch.xsd due to: protocol = http host = null
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:910)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:780)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2068)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1816)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1683)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1651)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:254)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:120)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: properties://%7B%7Bvalidator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch%7D%7D due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: validator://http://tomcat-test:8080/ecitationinternal/xsd/Odyssey/current/NM/NMEFileBatch.xsd due to: protocol = http host = null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:534)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:71)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:106)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:112)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:55)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:459)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:428)
    at org.apache.camel.model.TryDefinition.createProcessor(TryDefinition.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:499)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:212)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:907)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: validator://http://tomcat-test:8080/ecitationinternal/xsd/Odyssey/current/NM/NMEFileBatch.xsd due to: protocol = http host = null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:534)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.createEndpoint(PropertiesComponent.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:514)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
    at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:170)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:926)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ResourceHelper.resolveResourceAsInputStream(ResourceHelper.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ResourceHelper.resolveMandatoryResourceAsInputStream(ResourceHelper.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.component.validator.DefaultLSResourceResolver$DefaultLSInput.getInputUri(DefaultLSResourceResolver.java:108)
    at org.apache.camel.component.validator.DefaultLSResourceResolver$DefaultLSInput.<init>(DefaultLSResourceResolver.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.component.validator.DefaultLSResourceResolver$DefaultLSInput.<init>(DefaultLSResourceResolver.java:88)
    at org.apache.camel.component.validator.DefaultLSResourceResolver.resolveResource(DefaultLSResourceResolver.java:85)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.DOMEntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(DOMEntityResolverWrapper.java:109)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1070)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:659)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchemaSource(XSDHandler.java:2105)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1088)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:620)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:616)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:574)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:540)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:252)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:627)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.validation.ValidatingProcessor.createSchema(ValidatingProcessor.java:364)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.validation.ValidatingProcessor.loadSchema(ValidatingProcessor.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.component.validator.ValidatorComponent.createEndpoint(ValidatorComponent.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:514)
    ... 37 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem launching or running Camel
    at gov.nmcourts.camelvm.CamelManager.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route EFileBatchRequestValidate at: >>> DoTry[[To[properties:{{validator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch}}], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.request.validatedtracsxsd}}], DoCatch[ null -> [To[exceptionResponseProcessor], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.request.rejected}}], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.response}}]]]]] <<< in route: Route(EFileBatchRequestValidate)[[From[properties:{{queue.ef... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: properties://%7B%7Bvalidator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch%7D%7D due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: validator://http://tomcat-test:8080/ecitationinternal/xsd/Odyssey/current/NM/NMEFileBatch.xsd due to: protocol = http host = null
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1363)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:122)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:157)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:147)
    at gov.nmcourts.camelvm.CamelManager.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route EFileBatchRequestValidate at: >>> DoTry[[To[properties:{{validator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch}}], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.request.validatedtracsxsd}}], DoCatch[ null -> [To[exceptionResponseProcessor], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.request.rejected}}], To[properties:{{queue.efilebatch.response}}]]]]] <<< in route: Route(EFileBatchRequestValidate)[[From[properties:{{queue.ef... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: properties://%7B%7Bvalidator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch%7D%7D due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: validator://http://tomcat-test:8080/ecitationinternal/xsd/Odyssey/current/NM/NMEFileBatch.xsd due to: protocol = http host = null
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:910)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:780)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2068)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1816)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1683)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1651)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:254)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:120)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: properties://%7B%7Bvalidator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch%7D%7D due to: Failed to resolve endpoint: validator://http://tomcat-test:8080/ecitationinternal/xsd/Odyssey/current/NM/NMEFileBatch.xsd due to: protocol = http host = null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:534)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:71)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:106)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:112)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:55)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:459)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:428)
    at org.apache.camel.model.TryDefinition.createProcessor(TryDefinition.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:499)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:212)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:907)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: validator://http://tomcat-test:8080/ecitationinternal/xsd/Odyssey/current/NM/NMEFileBatch.xsd due to: protocol = http host = null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:534)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.createEndpoint(PropertiesComponent.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:514)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
    at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:170)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:926)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ResourceHelper.resolveResourceAsInputStream(ResourceHelper.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ResourceHelper.resolveMandatoryResourceAsInputStream(ResourceHelper.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.component.validator.DefaultLSResourceResolver$DefaultLSInput.getInputUri(DefaultLSResourceResolver.java:108)
    at org.apache.camel.component.validator.DefaultLSResourceResolver$DefaultLSInput.<init>(DefaultLSResourceResolver.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.component.validator.DefaultLSResourceResolver$DefaultLSInput.<init>(DefaultLSResourceResolver.java:88)
    at org.apache.camel.component.validator.DefaultLSResourceResolver.resolveResource(DefaultLSResourceResolver.java:85)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.DOMEntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(DOMEntityResolverWrapper.java:109)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1070)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:659)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchemaSource(XSDHandler.java:2105)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1088)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:620)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:616)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:574)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:540)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:252)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:627)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.validation.ValidatingProcessor.createSchema(ValidatingProcessor.java:364)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.validation.ValidatingProcessor.loadSchema(ValidatingProcessor.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.component.validator.ValidatorComponent.createEndpoint(ValidatorComponent.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:514)
    ... 37 more
```

I have not changed the route from when it worked. I only changed jar files/versions/dependencies/etc. (and also upgraded from java-1.6 to java 1.7). The route looks something like:

```
        ... etc
        <doTry>
            <to id="tracsValidator" uri="properties:{{validator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch}}" />
            <to uri="properties:{{queue.efilebatch.request.validatedtracsxsd}}" />
        <doCatch>
        ... etc
```

where the validator property is defined as:

```
validator.efilebatch.TRACSEFileBatch=validator://http://tomcat-test:8080/ecitationinternal/xsd/Odyssey/current/NM/NMEFileBatch.xsd
```

I am able to reach the host and URL in question from the box. From the command line, I can issue a wget and retrieve the xsd file successfully. The xsd file has not changed from the previous (working) version, either. Googling and poking and prodding haven't led me to a solution thus far. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Can you check if you have the proxy setting on the JVM ?

Comment: I talked to my network admin and he says I don't need a proxy. However, before asking him I had tried setting a proxy with -Dhttp.proxyHost=... and -Dhttp.proxyPort=... and it didn't solve the issue. Is there some other place the JVM would get proxy info other than that?

Comment: One other data point: I wrote a simple java stand-alone test, to retrieve the xsd file via http, and it worked fine (without setting any proxy information with -D... or anything special).

Comment: Oh, my point is you should remove the proxy setting. From the stack trace, I can tell there is something wrong with the setting of the proxy host.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment wasn't clear. I meant to say that I have tried both with and without setting any proxy, and it fails in any event. Is there some other mechanism (transparent to me, i.e. w/o -D flags) that the proxy might be getting picked up? The same code when using camel-2.9 and associated dependencies appears to work on the exact same machine. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: There are some code changes of camel-validate in the camel-2.10, can you provide a small test case to reproduce the error?

Comment: I'm also getting the same error when attempting to validate against the FHIR message header schema (http://www.hl7.org/fhir/messageheader.xsd).  Could it be that this schema has a relative include `<xs:include schemaLocation="fhir-base.xsd"/>` and its the include not resolving correctly?